# How to run artisan queue:work from browser and send it to background

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

In terminal if I run `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 &`

the command will start and it will be sent to background...

but in Laravel if I run `Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--option' => 'tries=3'.' &']);`

I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidOptionException: The "--option" option does not exist. in /var/www/html/laravel/exercise/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArrayInput.php:172
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/laravel/exercise/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArrayInput.php(134): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput->addLongOption('option', 'tries=1 &')
```

and if i run `Artisan::queue('queue:work');`

the command works but it's an infinite loop and it just blocks the whole app.

So is there a way to run the queue:work from the app and send it to background like in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things should be seperated here:

**Queueing jobs**

```
Artisan::queue('command:name', $options);
```

This tells Artisan to, whenever the queue processor is working, execute `command:name`.

---

**Running an artisan command**

From my perspective, this is the thing you are looking for. To execute a specific Artisan command from your app, you can also use the `call` method on the Artisan facade.

```
Artisan::call('queue:work');
```

Another problem is that you are specifying the *options* in the wrong way. Try this:

```
Artisan::call('queue:work', ['--tries' => 3]);
```

Comment: Yes it works but I want to send that process in background...if I run it like this it is like an infinite loop. The browser spins and my app is like blocked

Comment: Allright, then this is not the way to go. You will need something like Supervisor or another Daemon to make sure Artisan is *listening* to your queue. Read about it  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener)

Comment: I already read that...but to be short here my goal is to start queue:work and then stop it after the jobs table is empty I tried it with exec() command and it works sort of but the browser spins also